# ASP.Net DataList HTML5 conformance

Tags: asp.net, html

In trying to make my ASP.Net 4.0 site validate to HTML5 the best I can with the current specification. I have a DataList that always adds cellspacing="0" I've tried different ways of removing the cellspacing="0". I have added a CSS style sheet which does flow over.

Anyone know how to make the DataList conform to the HTML 5 validation?

Actual Code:

Validation Error Message: The cellspacing attribute on the table element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.

Generated Code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a big fan of `DataList` - many time, the markup generates is table based and hence semantically incorrect. So I will suggest to use some alternate control such as Repeater or ListView if possible.

Now, if you are in situation where you have plenty of data lists... one of the solution would be to have your own custom `DataList` control to explicitly override cellspacing attribute such as

```
public class MyDataList : DataList
{
    protected override Style CreateControlStyle()
    {
        var s = new TableStyle();
        s.CellSpacing = -1;
        return s;
    }
}
```

You can then probably use [ASP.NET Tag Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164641.aspx) to substitute built-in data-list with your implementation across all pages from config.